# What is the meaning of Frank-N-Furter's words to Rocky?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-rocky-horror-picture-show

In one scene in [The Rocky Horror Picture Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073629/), Frank-N-Furter says this to Rocky:

> In just seven days, I can make you a man

[image]

Rocky is already a man with muscles.

What is the meaning of Frank-N-Furter's words to Rocky?

Comment: You might want to think about [**merging accounts**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) instead of creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 6):

The "words" are actually part of a song called *"I Can Make You a Man"*.

Essentially, Rocky was created by Frank-N-Furter after Frank discovered what he called "spark that is the breath of life".

When Rocky is 'born' he compliments Frank on his body and Frank says that he's the result of a lot of work.

> ROCKY. [snip]..But I do think you made a pretty good job of the body work.
>
> FRANK. You are the result of many hours of toil - and now my beautiful creature you're ready for the ultimate test.

The song starts afterwards which basically says that the old way of getting your body to look that way was lot of exercise & proper diet...but now there is a new way...he can **literally** make a man in 7 days.

[image]

> <sup>[Script Source](http://www.rockymusic.org/showdoc/rhs-1999-script.php)</sup>

---

There is also an implied sexual overtone with the words "make you a man" as this is also a reference to rites of passage usually involving losing ones virginity.

Comment: still missing the essential wordplay, in just 7 days, I can make a man ***for*** you [you being Brad & the audience], rather than 'turn you into a man'.

Comment: I do mention that... *"he can **literally** make a man in 7 days."*

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking in terms of, for instance a tailor says "In just 7 days I can make you a suit" then there would be little room for confusion. Frank, however, has a whole different take on life...

Comment: Or the old joke, "My mother made me a homosexual." "If I give her the wool, will she make me one too?" It's a 'simple' wordplay, but you probably need to be an English native to fully see the layers to it.

Answer (score 1):

The song lyric is a play on the old ads claiming that a short course at the gym could give you a muscular body by using the euphemism "make you a man", which means to take a "boy's" virginity.

Of course, he's also speaking to his audience, since he's just demonstrated that he can "make a man", and could presumably do so again, if anyone else wanted one.

Comment: It's a 3-way wordplay. 1) The old Charles Atlas ads. 2) Taking his virginity, turning him from a boy to a man & 3) He, of course, just **made** Rocky, literally, like his namesake Frankenstein.

Comment: True. That slipped my mind. Added.